# Segmentation Fault in Node.JS application running in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, segmentation-fault

I need some help understanding the reason why I encounter a Segmentation Fault when running my application. It usually happens during an API call of some kind.

I've added the segfault-handler package had it has provided me with stack trace.

```
PID 39 received SIGSEGV for address: 0xae017c6b000
/opt/<redacted>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x3236)[0x7efdbc5bc236]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x13140)[0x7efdbf1de140]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x16fb97)[0x7efdbf165b97]
node(_ZN2v88internal4wasm12NativeModule20AddCodeWithCodeSpaceEiRKNS0_8CodeDescEijNS_4base6VectorIKhEES9_NS1_8WasmCode4KindENS1_13ExecutionTierENS1_12ForDebuggingENS7_IhEERKNS2_13JumpTablesRefE+0x103)[0x1509753]
node(_ZN2v88internal4wasm12NativeModule15AddCompiledCodeENS_4base6VectorINS1_21WasmCompilationResultEEE+0x228)[0x150f268]
node[0x14d5ffe]
node[0x14d64eb]
node(_ZN2v88platform16DefaultJobWorker3RunEv+0x84)[0x1ad41e4]
node[0xbd4b45]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7ea7)[0x7efdbf1d2ea7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f)[0x7efdbf0f2aef]
Segmentation fault
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

It is running in the node:18-bullseye-slim image, using Node 18.6.0. Comment if you need me to provide more information.

Comment: I have a very similar issue, and can't find much reference on the internet on how to proceed next :(

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3bfd0)[0x7fbfc2901fd0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x163b14)[0x7fbfc2a29b14]
node(_ZN2v88internal4wasm12NativeModule20AddCodeWithCodeSpaceEiRKNS0_8CodeDescEijNS_4base6VectorIKhEES9_NS1_8WasmCode4KindENS1_13ExecutionTierENS1_12ForDebuggingENS7_IhEERKNS2_13JumpTablesRefE+0x103)[0x1518ad3]
node(_ZN2v88internal4wasm12NativeModule15AddCompiledCodeENS_4base6VectorINS1_21WasmCompilationResultEEE+0x228)[0x151e5e8]
```

Comment: I found out what the issue was, it's related to the Docker version I was using on Mac OSX

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6824

To fix this, go to your Docker Settings, General, then untick Use Virtualization Framework

Answer (score 9):

I found out what the issue was, it's related to the Docker version I was using on Mac OSX

[github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6824](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6824)

To fix this, go to your Docker Settings, General, then untick Use Virtualization Framework –

Comment: Worked on Intel Mac running Docker 24.0.5

Comment: Worked for me also - changed setting from `VirtioFS` (which implies Virtualization Framework) to `gRPC FUSE`, then disabled `Virtualization Framework`.

On top of that, docker for mac was crashing at start, and I had to kill the docker backend process manually then retry.

PS: "thanks" docker team for the dodgy "minor" upgrades so far

Comment: Thanks for saving my life on this one lol. Worked for me on 24.0.6