Docker: ng build: Segmentation fault error
I have the Problem that i can't build the docker image of my angular frontend.
The command RUN npm run ng build --aot --base-href=/ --configuration=dev throws a Segmentation fault  error
What I Excecute:
docker build -t {{url}}:{{tag}} --platform linux/amd64 --build-arg conf=dev --build-arg path=frontend .
Error:
Terminal-Logs of the Error:

[builder 6/7] RUN npm install \
ERROR [builder 7/7] RUN npm run ng build --aot --base-href=/ --configuration=dev \
[builder 7/7] RUN npm run ng build --aot --base-href=/ --configuration=dev:
project@5.2.1 ng
ng build
Segmentation fault
------
Dockerfile:11
--------------------
9 |     ARG conf
10 |     RUN npm install
11 | >>> RUN npm run ng build --aot --base-href=/ --configuration=$conf
12 |
13 |     FROM nginx:1.25.4-alpine
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run ng build --aot --base-href=/ --configuration=$conf" did not complete successfully: exit code: 139

Ressources
Here is the Docker-File:
FROM node:18.18.2 as builder

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci && mkdir /ng-app
WORKDIR /ng-app
COPY . .

ARG conf
RUN npm install
RUN npm run ng build --aot --base-href=/ --configuration=$conf


FROM nginx:1.25.4-alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist/frontend .


UPDATE: package.json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "5.2.2",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "compodoc": "npx compodoc -p tsconfig.doc.json",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.13",
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^16.2.12",
    "@ngneat/tailwind": "^7.0.3",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@zxcvbn-ts/core": "^3.0.4",
    "@zxcvbn-ts/language-en": "^3.0.2",
    "angular-password-strength-meter": "^9.0.1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.2",
    "captcha-eu-sdk": "^1.0.2",
    "clean-deep": "^3.4.0",
    "cypress-real-events": "^1.7.6",
    "deep-object-diff": "^1.1.9",
    "eslint-plugin-deprecation": "^1.5.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.33",
    "keycloak-angular": "^14.1.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^22.0.5",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.51",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^12.0.2",
    "ngx-matomo-client": "^5.0.4",
    "node": "^20.10.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^16.9.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "yaml": "^2.3.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^16.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^16.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^16.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.7",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.4",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.5",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.18.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "cypress": "^13.6.2",
    "cypress-keycloak-commands": "^1.2.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.18.20",
    "eslint": "^8.54.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.1",
    "htmlhint": "^1.1.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.0.1",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.26",
    "prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.12.0"
  }
}

Docker Desktop Ressources:

CPU limit 8
Memory limit: 14 GB
Swap: 2 GB
Virtual disk limit: 192 GB

Additional Informations
I can execute the command without problems local (ng build --aot --base-href=/ --configuration=dev ).
Other Team-Members can build the exact same docker image without problems. (One has the same error as I)
Local Versions:

Angular: 16.2.12
Node: 18.18.2
npm: 10.5.1
OS: darwin x64 & macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
Docker: 25.0.3

Steps I tried already:

Reinstalling Docker, angular

Updated Docker, Node, NPM to newer versions (not always to the latest because of angular 16.x)

Checked Compatibility of the modules (Angular, Node, NPM)

Give Docker more ressources

Testet command outside of docker -> It works local

Docker File could not be the problem, because it works for other team-members.


What I Expect:
I am new to docker & angular. I would be grateful for some hints how I can solve the Problems.
Please let me know if you need any additional informations.
Kind regards
Update
Another Team-Member has now the same Problems after updating his MacOS from 13.x.x to 14.4.1

can you please add your package.json? also if your team is using something non standard(standard would be just pure angular cli) in the build, would be nice to share as well

I could resolve the issue. So here the solution for completeness.
Solution

Got to Docker Desktop/Settings/General
switch "Choose file sharing implementation for your containers" to gRPC FUSE
Uncheck Use Virtualization framework

Docker-Settings
Solution found in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77048546
